# Deleted CRUD Table Facade.class still being generated: how to remove?

Tags: jsf-2, netbeans-7, crud, derby

I removed a table from my Derby database, re-generated the 'Entity classes from database' and regenerated the CRUD files in Netbeans 7.0.1 but it keeps generating a Facade.class file for the deleted table: 'SEARCH_CRITERIA_TBL'.

I have deleted everything I can find related to the CRUD and done a clean and rebuild but it insists on regenerating the file:

\NetBeansProjects\Server\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\JSFBeans\SearchCriteriaTblFacade.class

The project compiles but the server fails to start with the following error:

> Blockquote
>   WARNING: Exception while starting bundle com.sun.enterprise.osgi-adapter [154]
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle com.sun.enterprise.osgi-adapter [154].
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1751)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1622)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:915)
>       at org.jvnet.hk2.osgimain.Main.start(Main.java:140)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:640)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1700)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1622)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1077)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that
    is not native or abstract in class file JSFBeans/SearchCriteriaTblFacade        

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:920)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:247)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:541)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:433)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:420)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:373)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:247)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:208)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:148)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:162)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:79)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:612)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:554)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:262)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:362)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:185)
at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractWombImpl.inject(AbstractWombImpl.java:174)
at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorWomb$1.run(ConstructorWomb.java:87)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorWomb.initialize(ConstructorWomb.java:84)
at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractWombImpl.get(AbstractWombImpl.java:77)
at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:58)
at com.sun.hk2.component.LazyInhabitant.get(LazyInhabitant.java:107)
at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:60)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:236)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:128)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.launch(Main.java:457)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.launch(Main.java:401)
at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.HK2Main.start(HK2Main.java:125)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:640)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1700)
... 9 more
```

Searches of the net only tell me what the 'JSF from Entity Classes' does not how it works internally. No doubt I am searching on the wrong terms...

Does anyone know where the Facade.classes create data is kept or can anyone tell me what terms I need to search on to find out? I have searched the entire project and found no reference to 'SearchCriteriaTbl' or 'SEARCH_CRITERIA_TBL'. I have manually deleted the SearchCriteriaTblFacade.class file, but it still reappears when the project is cleaned and rebuilt.

Kind thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: I re-inserted the deleted table into the database, regenerated the entity classes and CRUD files, and recompiled. Then removed the table again, re-created the entity classes from database and re-did CRUD creation. I then did a refactor delete rather than a normal delete of the unneeded files. After about three clean and recompiles it eventually sorted itself out and is now working.